# dataset.repeat() will cause the infinite loop?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, dataset

I am learning Tensorflow by reading the official document. But confused by this line:

`dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000).repeat()`

I try to run this whole project, it can actually work. But I don't understand why it won't step into the endless loop caused by dataset.repeat(), because you don't assign the count so it will repeat indefinitely.

Hope anyone can help me to figure this out?

Here is the link to this line of code:https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimator/premade

It is in part "define the feature columns" and the whole code block is copied below:

````
    """An input function for training or evaluating"""
    # Convert the inputs to a Dataset.
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(features), labels))

    # Shuffle and repeat if you are in training mode.
    if training:
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000).repeat()

    return dataset.batch(batch_size)```
````

Comment: Thank you so much, I got your meaning. I am still wondering what's the benefit to do that, rather than assign the count directly like repeat(500) or others? (Maybe it is more elegant to limit the count by just assign the total steps because it will allow to shuffle the data as much as possible within the expected calculation?  Here is just my guess)

Comment: I turned my comments into an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *does* step into an infinite loop. If you wonder how training could have been finished, the documentation indicates that steps argument has been provided in

```py
classifier.train(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(train, train_y, training=True), steps=5000)
```

so even though the loop is infinite, the optimizer know how many steps to perform.

As to the question why do to do it in this way... I think it is a matter of personal preference, however, there is a scenario where this could be very useful. Let's look into function that generates `tf.data.Dataset` for training and testing:

```py
def input_fn(features, labels, training=True, batch_size=256):
    """An input function for training or evaluating"""
    # Convert the inputs to a Dataset.
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(features), labels))

    # Shuffle and repeat if you are in training mode.
    if training:
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000).repeat()

    return dataset.batch(batch_size)
```

Now, let's say you want to study how batch size influence the way your model learns. To compare models with different batch size and be fair about it, you should allow each model for the same amount of iterations (weights updates). The difference should be that models with bigger batch size will better approximate gradient over the entire dataset. Using the setup from abovementioned tutorial it is very easy to do. You will just change the `batch_size` parameter in `input_fn` and since number of steps is constant, your pipeline is ready to go. Trying to do it in another way can be painful